# How to write a SQL WHERE statement with multiple entries that should exist in a set of columns

Tags: sql, database

I have the following database table:

```
| id | First  | Second | Third   |
+----+--------+--------+---------+
| 1  | Barack | Donald | Hillary |
| 2  | Barack | Donald | Joe     |
| 3  | Barack | George | Joe     |
| 4  | Dwight | Donald | Joe     |
| 5  | Joe    | George | Barack  |
```

I am looking for an SQL statement to filter rows where `Barack` AND `Joe` are part of the columns. In this case, the solution would be the rows with ids `2`,`3`, and `5`. Obviously, I can build a very ugly statement with lots of `OR` and `AND` but I am looking for a simple solution. In pseudocose, I imagine something like

```sql
SELECT * from database WHERE ('Barack' AND 'Joe') in (First, Second, Third)
```

Looks like this should be a very simple statement to me, but I was not able to google it. Can you help me?

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "very ugly statement with lots of `OR` and  `AND`" you speak-of really isn't that bad:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    tableName
WHERE
    ( First = 'Barack' OR Second = 'Barack' OR Third = 'Barack' )
    AND
    ( First = 'Joe' OR Second = 'Joe' OR Third = 'Joe' )
```

Fun fact: the `IN` operator can be used in reverse-order:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    tableName
WHERE
    'Barack' IN ( First, Second, Third )
    AND
    'Joe' IN ( First, Second, Third )
```

That's is pretty simple, no?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, you are right, it is not that ugly as I expected. But nevertheless, this is just a small example. Let's suppose I have a lot of columns and conditions ... In this case, I would have to write a lot of these OR and AND statements ...

Comment: @PanchoVarallo See my updated answer that uses the `IN` operator. But if the question you've posted is not representative of your **real query** then my answer is useless. You should update your question with your **real problem**, not an oversimplification.

Comment: Wow, the second looks very nice ... I just checked it and I really like it.